# Variable inside variable in Java

Tags: java, variables

I would like to use the "int i", inside an if statement (where i wrote +i+).

**Here's the code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i <6; i++) { 
 if (mouseX > mindmap.c+i+mX - mindmap.c+i+.mD / 2 && mouseX < mindmap.c+i+.mX + mindmap.c+i+.mD / 2) {
  if (mouseY > mindmap.c1.mY - mindmap.c1.mD / 2 && mouseY < mindmap.c1.mY + mindmap.c1.mD / 2) {
    println("hej");
  }
}
```

I want my loop to use the variable `mindmap.c0.mX` in the first iteration in the loop, after that `mindmap.c1.mX` on second iteration, then `mindmap.c2.mX` and so on. Can this be done?

We are using Processing as the tool.

Comment: yes, it can be done! is your code not working?

Comment: Why not test it and see? But yes, that's valid usage.

Comment: What is `mindmap`?

Comment: What is __mX__?

Comment: This bit: `mindmap.c+i+.mD` does not seem to be correct. Provide at least the definition of `mindmap` and a description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If i understand you correct you want your loop to use the variable mindmap.c0mX in the first iteration in the loop, after that mindmap.c1mX on second iteration, then mindmap.c2mX and so on? You could probably archieve that with refleciton, but i would rather use another data structure like an array or Collection.

Comment: 911DidBush is correct!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a local variable is in the block in which it is defined from the line where it is defined.

```
... // i not visible
{   // Start of block

    ...
    // i not visible
    int i = 0;    // Definition of variable i visible from here
    ....

    // Last line where is possible to use the variable i
}   // End of block
// i not visible
```

In your case is possible to use the variable i in the whole for loop.

The problem in your code is not related to the visibility of the i variable, but it is syntactically not correct.

`.mD` and `.mX` are not correct name of variables. Here is the problem. Probably you need to write only `mD` and `mX` .